# Firebird, query in c#, different queries on different values, how to construct and simplify it?

Tags: c#, firebird

Have checkbox for month, checkbox for year and
following code (pseudo code):

```
if(month.checked) query = select* from tab where month=month.text;
if(year.checked) query = select* from tab where year=year.text;
if(month.checked and year.checked) query = select * from tab where month=month.value and year=year.value
if(!month.checked and !year.checked) query = select* from tab
```

So as you see there is 4 different queries.
Is it possible to do it faster, in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could make one query of this, but the query gets a lot more complex and that usually leads to slower queries. Unless you have a compelling reason to do it, just stick to separate queries.

Something like the query below would do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE ? IS NOT NULL AND month = ?
OR ? IS NOT NULL AND year = ?
OR ? IS NULL AND ? IS NULL
```

Here parameter 1 and 5 are the indicator if month is checked (NULL means not checked, a value means checked), parameter 2 the value of month.text, parameter 3 and 6 the indicator if year is checked and parameter 4 the value of year.text.

Comment: Thanks, but what if i have more checkboxes, like 5 or more? It will become more than 120 queries...it would be better to use above solution or it will also be very slow?

Comment: You could use the construct above, but you would really need to test how well it performs. You might want to consider dynamically constructing the query (ie only add the query condition if the checkbox is checked)